# What is the appropriate placement of \label in a 'figure' environment

Tags: graphics, floats, captions

I found that if I don't place \label in a \begin{figure}...\end{figure} correctly, it will generate a ?? when I \autoref it.

Where is the appropriate position?

```
\begin{figure}
\label{}
\includegraphics{}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{}
\label{}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
```

or

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics{}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: LaTeX tries to associate the argument of `\label` with the most recently incremented counter variable -- here: the `figure` counter. The `figure` counter gets incremented by the `\caption` directive. Hence, the only possible correct answer in your list is #3.

Comment: A fourth (working) variant is `\caption{text\label{label}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Wow this could be very clean

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Unfortunately TexStudio produces a ugly green squiggly line used to show potential syntax error (despite no error). I guess your solution is too advanced haha.

Comment: but it is better, a \label behind a caption can affect spacing in some cases.